# Context Deadline exceeded for go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

Working with Go routines, I am setting a deadline of maximum 30 seconds for each of them, the code is something like this:

```golang
func processLibs(ctx context.Context, libs []Library) {
    for _, lib := range libs {
        go processLib(ctx, lib)
    }
}

func processLib(ctx context.Context, lib Library) {
    cancelContext, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second * 30)
    defer cancel()

    if err := persistLib(cancelContext, lib); err != nil {
        log.Error("error persisting library", log.Err(err))
    }
}
```

Where persistLib does 7 queries to the DB (max conns and max idle conns equals 5) and one request to another server (the outgoing request times are ok). I know as a fact, that the length of libs is less or equal than 100.

The problem that I'm having, is that sometimes, I have a batch of errors (about 20% of the go routines) saying that the context expired, but I find really weird that a go routine that does just that takes 30 seconds (measuring it, it should be fine).

I tried reducing the amount of go routines to 70 or 50, but the problem is still there. I also tried checking for performance improvements, but the some go routines send a deadline error in the middle of the first query, some of them at the end of the go routine execution, it depends.

My DB is a MySQL 8.0 and I am using GO 1.19.

Comment: "I find really weird that a go routine that does just that takes 30 seconds" why is that weird? You have a timeout of 30 seconds, I would expect a run that times out to take exactly 30 seconds since that's the point where it's supposed to stop.

Comment: If the persistLib function is such a long running task, you could simply try a longer timeout. Change it to 60 seconds maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The real question is what transaction do you want to timeout here? Or in other words what transaction(s) do you expect to be finished in 30 seconds?
Looking at the code you just need to call your *persistLib* as

```
persistLib(cancelContext, lib)
```

This way you will wait for 30 seconds on each persist operation. Currently your code is waiting for whatever number of seconds set in *ctx* on all persist operations.